# Dynamically generate controls are not generating on textbox OnTextChanged event in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am trying to generate dynamic controls on texbox OnTextChange event. I put break point texbox OnTextChange event but it is not entering in it.
I am using ajax toolkit autocomplete extender to get Users name from database into textbox.When full name of user entered in textbox then this event will fire but it is not working.
Any Solution

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
<ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server"
  ServiceMethod="GetUsers" ServicePath="WebService1.asmx"
MinimumPrefixLength="1"
CompletionInterval="100" EnableCaching="false" CompletionSetCount="10"
TargetControlID="TextBox1" FirstRowSelected="false" ></ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
<asp:Label ID="webpageNames" runat="server"></asp:Label>


<asp:Button id="new" runat="server" OnClick="new_Click">
</asp:Button>
<asp:Panel ID="lblPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="cbPanel" runat="server"></asp:Panel>

public static List<string> getWebPagesName()
        {
            List<string> li = new List<string>();
            li.Add("AssignRoles");
            li.Add("Roles");

            return li;
        }

        int o = getWebPagesName().Count;
  public void showControls()
        {
            List<string> lblli = getWebPagesName();
            for (int i = 0; i < o; i++)
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                Label lbl = new Label();

                cb.Text = "Allow";

                lbl.Text = lblli[i].ToString();
                lblPanel.Controls.Add(lbl);
                cbPanel.Controls.Add(cb);
            } 
       }

        protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            showControls();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add AutoPostback = "true" on the text box definition:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" AutoPostback="true"></asp:TextBox>
```